# Export PDF margins different in V9 & V10 compared with version 7

Tags: graphics

PDFs in version 9 and 10 have bigger margins than in version 7.  I can't find any differences in the settings.  I'm using A4 paper and it looks like version 9 might be trying to use letter size.  Anyone know how I can get the original version 7 output?

***Example PDF outputs from the code below***

[image]

```
(* Temporary session page settings *)
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,
 PrintingOptions -> {
   "PrintingMargins" -> {{45, 43}, {17, 31}},
   "FirstPageHeader" -> False,
   "FirstPageFooter" -> False,
   "RestPagesHeader" -> False,
   "RestPagesFooter" -> False}]

x = 629; y = 973;
page = Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {x, y}],
    Inset[Graphics[{Yellow, Disk[{x/2, x/2}, x/2]},
      PlotRange -> {{0, x}, {0, x}}],
     {x/2, y/2}, {Center, Center}, {x, x}]},
   PlotRange -> {{0, x}, {0, y}}, ImageSize -> {x, y}];
nb = CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[page, "Print"], Visible -> False];
Export["nb.pdf", nb];
NotebookClose[nb]
```

Comment: A4 paper is 595x842 printer points and your ImageSize->{x,y} is larger than that. So the Graphics must be scaled to fit onto one physical A4 page. Mathematica version 8.0 gives the same result as your version 9 image.

Comment: Work-around solution here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85513/363