# Use Version 7 Print Environment Settings in Version 10

Tags: graphics

The following code produces very different PDF outputs in versions 7 and 10.  Is there some way to make Mathematic 10 produce the same print output as Mathematica 7?

```
(* Temporary session page settings *)
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,
 PrintingOptions -> {
   "PrintingMargins" -> {{45, 43}, {17, 31}},
   "FirstPageHeader" -> False,
   "FirstPageFooter" -> False,
   "RestPagesHeader" -> False,
   "RestPagesFooter" -> False,
   "Magnification" -> 1}]

text = StringReplace[StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "Prufrock"}], 4221],
   FromCharacterCode[{195, 162, 128, 194}] -> "'"];

square = Graphics[{Orange, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {70, 70}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 70}, {0, 70}}];

column = Table[Inset[square, {415, 100 i}, {Left, Bottom}, {70, 70}], {i, 0, 9}];

page = Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {500, 973}], Black,
    Inset[TextCell[text, LineSpacing -> {0, 16}, TextJustification -> 1],
     {0, 973}, {Left, Top}, {400, 973}], column},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {0, 973}}, ImageSize -> 500,
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontWeight -> "Plain", FontSize -> 14}];

nb = CreateDocument@ExpressionCell[page, "Print"];

filename = StringJoin["v", ToString[Round@$VersionNumber], ".pdf"];

Quiet@DeleteFile[filename];

Export[filename, nb];

NotebookClose[nb]
```

***Output Comparison***

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Changes to `PrintingMargins`, `LineSpacing`, `ImageSize` and `FontSize` got the version 10 output close to the version 7 original.  However changing font size is not evenly scalable.

Trying with `Magnification` didn't help.  Best would be to replicate the versions 7 "Printout" style environment, but this doesn't seem to be open to manipulation.

```
(* Temporary session page settings *)
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,
 PrintingOptions -> {
   "PrintingMargins" -> {{11, 43}, {15, 31}},
   "FirstPageHeader" -> False,
   "FirstPageFooter" -> False,
   "RestPagesHeader" -> False,
   "RestPagesFooter" -> False,
   "Magnification" -> 1}]

text = StringReplace[StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "Prufrock"}], 4221],
   FromCharacterCode[{195, 162, 128, 194}] -> "'"];

square = Graphics[{Orange, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {70, 70}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 70}, {0, 70}}];

column = Table[Inset[square, {415, 100 i}, {Left, Bottom}, {70, 70}], {i, 0, 9}];

page = Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {500, 973}], Black,
    Inset[TextCell[text, LineSpacing -> {0, 17}, TextJustification -> 1],
     {0, 973}, {Left, Top}, {400, 973}], column},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {0, 973}}, ImageSize -> 555,
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontWeight -> "Plain", FontSize -> 15.5}];

nb = CreateDocument@ExpressionCell[page, "Print"];

filename = StringJoin["v", ToString[Round@$VersionNumber], ".pdf"];

Quiet@DeleteFile[filename];

Export[filename, nb];

NotebookClose[nb]
```

[image]