# How to speed up TextJustification in Mathematica 10

Tags: graphics, bugs, output-formatting, text, crash

Based on this question: - [Version 7 print environment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85225/use-version-7-print-environment-settings-in-version-10) - I set up two 10 page test documents in version 7.0.1 and version 10.1.  The version 7 document exported to PDF in 4.18 seconds whereas the version 10 export took 424.6 seconds.

Can I speed up export from version 10?

These are the test exports.

**For Version 7**

```
time = DateList[];
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,
  PrintingOptions -> {"PrintingMargins" -> {{45, 43}, {17, 31}},
    "FirstPageHeader" -> False, "FirstPageFooter" -> False,
    "RestPagesHeader" -> False, "RestPagesFooter" -> False,
    "Magnification" -> 1}];
text = StringReplace[StringTake[
    ExampleData[{"Text", "Prufrock"}], 4221],
   FromCharacterCode[{195, 162, 128, 194, 153}] -> "'"];
square = Graphics[{Orange, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {70, 70}]},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 70}, {0, 70}}];
column = Table[Inset[square, {415, 100 i}, {Left, Bottom},
    {70, 70}], {i, 0, 9}];
page = Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {500, 973}], Black,
    Inset[TextCell[text, LineSpacing -> {0, 16},
      TextJustification -> 1], {0, 973}, {Left, Top}, {400, 973}],
    column}, PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {0, 973}}, ImageSize -> 500, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontWeight -> "Plain", FontSize -> 14}];
nb = CreateDocument[ConstantArray[ExpressionCell[page, "Print"], 10],
   WindowSize -> 800];
filename = StringJoin["v", ToString[Round@$VersionNumber], ".pdf"];
Quiet@DeleteFile[filename];
Export[filename, nb];
NotebookClose[nb];
DateDifference[time, DateList[], "Second"]
```

> {4.18004, Second}

**For Version 10**

```
time = DateList[];
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,
  PrintingOptions -> {"PrintingMargins" -> {{11, 43}, {15, 31}},
    "FirstPageHeader" -> False, "FirstPageFooter" -> False,
    "RestPagesHeader" -> False, "RestPagesFooter" -> False,
    "Magnification" -> 1}];
text = StringReplace[StringTake[
    ExampleData[{"Text", "Prufrock"}], 4221],
   FromCharacterCode[{195, 162, 128, 194, 153}] -> "'"];
square = Graphics[{Orange, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {70, 70}]},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 70}, {0, 70}}];
column = Table[Inset[square, {415, 100 i}, {Left, Bottom},
    {70, 70}], {i, 0, 9}];
page = Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {500, 973}], Black,
    Inset[TextCell[text, LineSpacing -> {0, 17},
      TextJustification -> 1], {0, 973}, {Left, Top}, {400, 973}],
    column}, PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {0, 973}}, ImageSize -> 555,
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontWeight -> "Plain", FontSize -> 15.5}];
nb = CreateDocument[ConstantArray[ExpressionCell[page, "Print"], 10],
   WindowSize -> 800];
filename = StringJoin["v", ToString[Round@$VersionNumber], ".pdf"];
Quiet@DeleteFile[filename];
Export[filename, nb];
NotebookClose[nb];
DateDifference[time, DateList[], "Second"]
```

> 424.599 s

Comment: It took 546 seconds on my Windows 7 system with Mathematica 10.2

Comment: The timings on V9 are like those on V7. It's a V10 thing

Comment: Both tests crash Mma 10.2 on OS X 10.10.5 on the Export statement.

Comment: I'll confirm that MMA 10.2 on Win7-64 also crashes irretrievably on the `Export` statement (the rest of the code is executed fine and fast).

Comment: I got 3.2194 seconds on my Macbook Air with Mathematica 10.0.0.0.

Comment: @BrianG - Thanks, I also tested it on a Macbook Air (OS X 10.10.5) and it didn't crash.  Both tests ran in about 90 seconds on Mma 10.1.  The tests that crashed ran on a Macbook Pro on Mma 10.2.

Comment: I can confirm that the Version 10 script above crashes Mathematica on both my desktop iMac and my Macbook Pro. Both are running OS X 10.10.5 and *Mathematica* 10.2.0.0. I have found that in general, I have to generate PDF files from notebooks by using the "Print" menu item and then OS X's "print to PDF" facility. If I try and use "Save As" from Mathematica to save as a PDF, I get a damaged PDF that won't open in Preview or etc.

Answer (score 6):

Wolfram support has pointed out that the problem is confined to the `TextJustification`, and if this is removed the page creation speeds up.

This isn't a solution if text justification is required.

Comment: Have they mentioned if this is going to be fixed?

Comment: I got acknowledgment that there is a problem that needs to be "identified and fixed".  I'll follow up when I've tested version 10.4 (on Windows).

Comment: @shrx Fixed in Mathematica 11 I am reliably informed.