# Front end crash on Export in 10.2 on OS X macbook air 6,2

Tags: mac-os-x, crash, printing

When trying to create a PDF (export, print-save as, save image as) fronted crashes. With both OS X Mavericks and El Capitan

My machine is:
Model: MacBookAir6,2, BootROM MBA61.0099.B19, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 1.7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.13f15

But with OS X El Capitan and the same mathematica 10.2 on a mac mini 6,2 works all fine.

The error log begins with
0 libpangocairo-1.0.0.dylib 0x00ed0f56 run_iterator_get_cgglyph + 22

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96955/consistent-crash-printing-from-mathematica-10-2-0-and-10-1-0-in-os-x-10-11-el-ca

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91638/front-end-crash-on-export-in-10-2-on-os-x

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94776/how-to-speed-up-pdf-export-in-mathematica-10